# how to efficiently track the use of space on a map, both objects and free areas

Tags: actionscript-3, performance, dictionary, pixel

OK I start with a blank map, which is 512x512 = 262144 pixels/locations.

I need a way to efficiently draw some objects on it, and then be able to find the areas of free space, so that later more different objects can be added to these free areas. I cant figure out the best way to store this data, or algorithms to find the free areas.

I had a working solution, but it took forever to compute. I'm working with AS3, in case that impacts what would be the best solution.

Any Advice? thanks.

Comment: When you look for free locations to allocate, do you allocate them 1x1, or do you need to find NxM free rectangular blocks?

Comment: after i've found a free block, I will be storing it as rectangle object containing its size and position I would think. Later if an object is added to this area, if there is room left it will be subdivided, otherwise marked as 'full'.

Comment: @davivid: Then you could look at the 2D space as a bipartite tree of areas, where alternate levels subdivide their rectangle horizontally and vertically. I did this years ago when I built a windowing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is plenty of methods to work with bitmaps at Bitmap and BitmapData classes.

I've never done anything like that, but you could try. I believe the best approach is to draw the objects at the map. Then, use the method bitmapData.getColorBoundsRect() to get the areas that are not free. These AS3 native methods are very, very fast!

Here is the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Cheers,
CaioToOn!

Comment: cool, this does seem like a great way to achieve what's needed - as long as the speed is there. I guess would then store the free areas in a Vector, which are then ready to be manipulated and updated. thanks

Comment: Yep, this is a pretty fast method! I adapted the snippet from here:

http://play.blog2t.net/fast-blob-detection

and finding all 360 white squares on my static image is well under a second.

Comment: Good to know it worked for case! Keep us up to date!

Cheers,
CaioToOn!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost identical to the issue of memory allocation in operating systems - issues of fragmentation, cleanup, appropriate contiguous space usage all appear there as well. I'd read on up how this problem is solved in OS's: [start on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation).

Comment: thanks for the tip, something I will definitely need to read up about.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use polygon-filling techniques. Consider your space as a set of scan lines, one scan line per Y coordinate. On each scan line, store a list of X coordinates representing transitions between free and occupied space.