# how to efficiently store occupied/unoccupied 2D space (with insertion)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, python-3.x, python

I have an X by Y space, where X and Y are determined by the sizes of the rectangles given to me.  I'm inserting oriented rectangles of a certain size into the space, one at a time.  Each insertion is as far left as possible, and then as far up as possible (so as close to (0,0) as I can).  What's the best way to represent this?  I'm implementing this in Python.  The top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831888/how-to-efficiently-track-the-use-of-space-on-a-map-both-objects-and-free-areas) question is helpful, but I was hoping for some Python-specific advice, as I'm pretty new to the language itself as well.

Thanks!

Comment: @S.Lott: I think the OP meant, "one at a time".

Comment: Yes, sorry, Marcelo is correct.  Thanks for the edit John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to efficiently pack rectangles, there are some established algorithms. Here's a Python implementation of one particular [algorithm](http://enichan.darksiren.net/wordpress/?p=49). There's also an article on packing lightmaps [here](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html) for which I have a [Python version](http://pastebin.com/7ixt3ayG) (I honestly don't remember whether I ported it myself, or got it from somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices for working in two-dimensional space like this.

1. A list of lists.  `[ [0, 0, ..., 0], [0, 0, ..., 0], ... [0, 0, ..., 0] ]` The outer list is the 'X' access, the inner list is the 'Y' access.  Each point is `space[x][y]`.  You build it with `space = list( list( EMPTY for j in range(Y_size) ) for i in range(X_size) )` or something similar.

   You mask off rectangles with some filler algorithm that sets values into a rectangular patch of space.

   ```
   for x in range( low, high ):
       for y in range ( low, high ):
           space[x][y]= FILLED # or whatever object you're putting there.
   ```
2. A mapping.  `{ (0,0): 0, (0,1): 0, ... (X,Y): 0 }`.  Each point is `space[x,y]`.  You build it with `space = dict( ( (x,y), EMPTY ) for x in range(X_size) for y in range(Y_size) )`.

   You mask off rectangles with almost the same filler algorithm.  Just change the syntax slightly.

Answer (score 0):

[Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) are often used for this sort of thing.  It sounds like you want a region quad tree.